# cs50 mario pyramid error when check50

Tags: c, cs50

I"m doing the Mario pyramid task for cs50 course, the code works but I get errors when I do check50. Someone advised at a moment to replace spaces with characters to see whats wrong and I did (a instead of space) but I still can't figure it out. There seems to be a problem with the spaces but i dont cant figure out what it is.

```
Expecting the following on standard out —

 #  #
##  ##
... but received the following on standard out instead 
— a#  #
  ##  ##
... but received the following on standard out instead —

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa#  #
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa##  ##
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa###  ###
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa####  ####
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa#####  #####
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa######  ######
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa#######  #######
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa########  ########
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa#########  #########
aaaaaaaaaaaaa##########  ##########
aaaaaaaaaaaa###########  ###########
aaaaaaaaaaa############  ############
aaaaaaaaaa#############  #############
aaaaaaaaa##############  ##############
aaaaaaaa###############  ###############
aaaaaaa################  ################
aaaaaa#################  #################
aaaaa##################  ##################
aaaa###################  ###################
aaa####################  ####################
aa#####################  #####################
a######################  ######################
#######################  #######################



#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
    int height;
    int row;
    int hash;
    int space;

    do
    { 
      printf("Height:");
      height =get_int();

    }
    while (height<0 || height>23);

      for (row = 0; row < height; row++) 
      {
              for (space = (height-row-2); space>= 0; space--)
              {
                printf ("a");
              }
              for (hash = 0; hash <= row; hash++)
              {
                printf ("#");
              }
                printf("  ");
                for (hash=0; hash <= row; hash++)
                {
                  printf("#");
                }
              printf("\n");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it's working just fine (read: it passed the check50).
Here's a screenshot

[image: mario.c]

Answer (score 0):

//i tweak your code a bit and now i get the right piramide thanks for //sharing your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
    int height;
    int row;
    int hash;
    int space;

    do
   {
      height=get_int("size:");

    }
        while (height<0 || height>8);

      for (row = 0; row < height; row++)
      {
              for (space = (height-row-2); space>= 0; space--)
              {
                printf (" ");
              }
              for (hash = 0; hash <= row; hash++)
             {
                printf ("#");
              }

              printf("\n");
      } 
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).